# Excel workbook customization is getting “Process can’t access file because it is being used by another process” when Dropbox is running

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, dropbox

I have an Excel add-in project where I add customization to workbook soon after I open the workbook.

```
                       // check if the file is readonly.
                       FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fullName);
                       bool isReadOnly = f.IsReadOnly;
                       f.IsReadOnly = false;

                        string[] nonpublicCachedDataMembers = null;

                        bool runAsLocal = !(ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed);

                        ServerDocument.AddCustomization(fullName,
                                                        assemblyLocation,
                                                        SolutionID,
                                                        codeBaseEnv,
                                                        runAsLocal,
                                                        out nonpublicCachedDataMembers);

                        f.IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
```

I’m getting an error saying “Process can’t access file because it is being used by another process” when I’m adding the customization to workbook. This only happened when “Dropbox” is running in background (files are not saved in Dropbox folder and antivirus software is turned off). I understand that this happens due to file is accessing by more than one process. Is there any known issue of such scenario or any workaround other than stopping Dropbox while I’m working in workbook customization?

Appreciate any support with this regard.

Comment: Try to use ProcessExplorer to identify which processes use the file. Encountering problem during launched Dropbox could be just a coincidence.

Comment: `f.IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;`    Is that not supposed to be a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make my workbook customization load by disabling the dropbox badge. But still don't know what process might be blocking Excel.

Ref: [Dropbox forum answer](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205651383-Excel-workbook-customization-is-getting-Process-can-t-access-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process-when-Dropbox-is-running?page=1#community_comment_207702346)